# What does variable-initialization line do in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, variable-initialization

Can someone please tell what the following line of VB.Net is initializing:

`Dim x As SomeType() = New SomeType(0) {}`

What holds `x` variable? Is it an array? How can it be translated to C# for example?

I guess `SomeType` is probably an anonymous type, but still have no clue...

Comment: Yes, `x` is an array.  Yes, it can be done in C#.  `SomeType` is not an anonymous type (they don't have "names"), but some user-defined class or struct.  The actual line of code looks a little odd, but then it's VB.NET :)  It looks like it's creating a one-element array, but again I'm not sure that will compile.

Comment: @Tim: It will compile, I use this syntax to instantiate lists of integers fairly often. The actual syntax I use is: `Dim lst as List(Of Integer) = new Integer() {val1, val2}.ToList`. I agree it looks odd but its pretty handy for unit testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
Dim x As SomeType() = New SomeType(0) {}
```

declares an array of `SomeType` objects, which can hold one instance of `SomeType`.

When declaring an array of objects the value that is passed into the constructor is the *max index* of the array. So this declaration is basically declaring an  array with a length of 1. The `{}` portion of the line is where you could define the values that should be stored in the array. If you were to change `SomeType` to `integer` you could instantiate and fill your array like:

```
Dim intArray as Integer() = New Integer(0) {7}
```

and that would give the first instance stored in the `intArray` variable a value of `7`.

`SomeType` is not an anonymous type. `SomeType` would be a class that would have to be defined somewhere in your app.

In C# I think the sytax would look like:

```
SomeType[] x = new SomeType[0];
```

I'm not exactly sure how you would accomplish the `{}` portion of the VB.NET line in C#.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply declaring and initializing an array of a given type.  In C# I think it would be, quite similarly:

```
SomeType[] x = new SomeType[0] { };
```

> Is it an array?

Yes.  VB uses `()` for arrays instead of C#'s `[]`.

> I guess SomeType is probably an anonymous type

No, it's a defined static type like any other.